# How to get varying number of coordinates of a dimension for different coordinates of another dimension in xarray.DataArray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to have an xarray.DataArray to store some results. The initialized resultant DataArray looks like this:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np 

time_steps = np.arange(5)
region_ids = ['region_'+str(i) for i in np.arange(5)]
cluster_ids = ['cluster_'+str(i) for i in np.arange(5)] #5 being max no. of clusters 

data = np.zeros((len(time_steps), len(region_ids), len(cluster_ids)))
data.fill(np.nan)

result = xr.DataArray(data, [('time', time_steps), 
                             ('region_ids', region_ids), 
                             ('cluster_ids', cluster_ids)])
```

Now imagine that I get my results for first region (`'region_0'`). According to the algorithm, 3 clusters are sufficient. So my results look something like:

```
result_region = np.random.rand(5,3)
```

When I try to save the results using the command below I get an error:

```
result.loc[:,'region_0',:] = result_region

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,3) into shape (5,5)
```

How can I delete the extra cluster coordinates and save the results?
Is it possible to have different number of cluster coordinates for different regions coordinates?

Thanks in advance.